# AWS Script bash on EC instance launch

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I would like to automate these steps:

- Unzip a zip package (is it possible loading this zip on S3 bucket and downloading it during script? If yes, how?)
- Edit apache configuration files (port.conf, /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf)
- Run apt-get commands.

I really do not know how to create a script file to be run on EC2 instance startup.

Could everybody help me, please?

Thank you really much

Comment: What OS are you using? If you use the default AWS-linux you can use CloudInit to do these kinds of things

Comment: If you're using CloudFormation this gives a decent example of running steps on instance startup: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html

Comment: @Exelian I could use CloudInit of course

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is [`User Data`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), that will give you the possibility to run your script when ec2 instance is launched

When you create your ec2 instance, in step 3 (configure instance details) go to the bottom of the script and click on "Advanced Details". From there you can enter your script.

If you're using a Amazon AMI, the CLI is built in and you can use it, make sure to have [ec2 IAM role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) defined with necessary rights on your AWS resources.

Now in terms of your script, this is vague but roughly:

1. you would run `aws s3 cp s3_file local_file` to download a zip file from s3 on the instance, use [`unzip`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86849/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-from-the-terminal) linux command to unzip the content
2. Edit your files using `sed`, `cat` or `>`, see this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)
3. run commands with `apt-get`

Note: you're running the user-data script as root, so you dont need `sudo` when running commands.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it and I will rate your answer.
It is possible to run this commands as a script automated?